# How to troubleshoot oAuth authentication in asp.net core Blazor App

Tags: .net-core, oauth, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to set up Strava authentication (which is plain oAuth2) in Asp.Net Core Blazor App.
I am rather new to Blazor & Web dev (more of a backend background), and I don't seem to find out how to troubleshoot the reason why the Authentication does not work.

When I click the oAuth login button on the Login page in the (default) Blazor Server App, I get redirected to the correct oAuth login screen (of Strava in my case), but after I successfully enter the credentials for that App, the login page shows an error `Error loading external login information.`

While I would obviously appreciate any help or tips that could point out what is wrong in my code, I'm mostly searching for a way to get better error information and troubleshooting capabilities here.  Setting a breakpoint in the EventHandler delegates does not show much.
[image: Screenshot]

This is the `Startup.cs` extract where I have configured the authentication setup :

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth("Strava",
    oAuthOptions =>
    {
        oAuthOptions.ClientId = "myappid"; 
        oAuthOptions.ClientSecret = "myclientsecret";
        oAuthOptions.Scope.Clear();        
        oAuthOptions.Scope.Add("read");
        oAuthOptions.CallbackPath = "/profile"; 
        oAuthOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize";
        oAuthOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/token";
        oAuthOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        oAuthOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents()
        {
            OnRemoteFailure = loginFailureHandler =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Error");
                Console.WriteLine(loginFailureHandler.Failure.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }, 
            OnAccessDenied = handler =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(handler.Response.StatusCode);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update that made things work for me, so maybe it can help other people.

I performed the following actions, in order to gain more control on the entire authentication process.

1. I scaffolded two pages, in which I then could debug & step through (and obviously also update and change things).  More information was found in [this post](https://andrewlock.net/customising-aspnetcore-identity-without-editing-the-pagemodel/):

   - Account.Login, which enables the customization of the actual login page `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc CotacolApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Login"`
   - Account.ExternalLogin, which enables the customization of the actual strava page `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc CotacolApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.ExternalLogin"`
2. I then found out that the `var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` always resulted in a `null` value.  And that was because I had to set the IdentityScheme to external.  ```
3. And after that, I had to run some custom logic to do the claim mapping.  Most of those details were written down in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158462/instagram-oauth-getexternallogininfoasync-always-returns-null-in-net-core-2-0/55970100) by @Morgeh.

Hope this can help people in the future.